# Regular expression to match multiple phrases

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that helps me get subsets of strings from a long string without running split methods multiple times, so I figured I could use regex but at the moment I failed.

Here is my input text:

```
Platform->Not Machine Specific Studio->Symantec Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security
```

Here's what I've tried with regexp

Try 1

regexp: `/[A-Z]+->([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)(\s*|([A-Z]|[0-9])+)*$/gim`

result: `Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security`

Try 2

regexp: `/[A-Z]+->([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)(\s*|([A-Z]|[0-9])+)*/gim`

result:

```
Platform->Not Machine Specific Studio

Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security
```

Expected result:

```
Platform->Not Machine Specific 

Studio->Symantec    

Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security
```

**Each line in the results should be a match**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex pattern:

```
\S+->.*?(?= \S+->|$)
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
\S+           match an initial key
->            match "->"
.*?           match a value, consisting of one or possibly more words, under reaching
(?= \S+->|$)  the next key followed by "->" OR the end of the string
```

**Edit:**

If you are doing this from a Python script, then I suggest using `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "Platform->Not Machine Specific Studio->Symantec Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security"
matches = re.findall(r'\S+->.*?(?= \S+->|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Platform->Not Machine Specific', 'Studio->Symantec',
 'Title->Symantec Promotional Book Home Internet Security']
```

Comment: This gives me 2 out of 3 matches, but it seems to be on the right track, I'm going to try to tweak it a bit.

Comment: @M_Armendariz It is giving _all_ matches in the regex demo.  Most likely, the issue has something to do with your regex tool/code.

Comment: Yeah that's what I realized, I'm going to test it in the code (after I check python documentation about regex, and If it's working I will accept it as the right answer).
Just to let know other people, the issue might be on this tool https://www.regextester.com

Comment: @M_Armendariz If you are using Python then I suggest `re.findall`, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot this simplified my problems and yes, that's what I used.

regextester.com seems to have an issue handling this kind of regex but it helped me know that (?= ....  is a look ahead.

Thanks again